# Processing files in a directory on different threads at the same time - Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, file

I would like to process all my CSV files in a directory at the same time by using threads. 
I got something but the files are not being processed. Can someone else help me?
It seems like my messages arraylist is staying empty and nothing is happening.
I used the Executorservice and I'm using spring too.

This is my **File Generator class**.

```
public class FileGenerator implements MessageGenerator {

@Getter
private static List<CameraMessage> messages;

private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger((FileGenerator.class.getName()));




public FileGenerator(String folderpath) {

    String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File inputfolder = new File(dir + folderpath);
    messages = new ArrayList<>();

    for (File fileEntry : inputfolder.listFiles()) {
        pool.execute((() -> {
            logger.info("pool executed");
            try {

                FileReader filereader = new FileReader(fileEntry);
                // Create csvReader object and skip first line (Header line)
                CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader)
                        //.withSkipLines(1)
                        .build();
                List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
                System.out.println();

                LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                // Create message list from CSV lines
                for (String[] row : allData) {
                    CameraMessage message = new CameraMessage(
                            Integer.parseInt(row[0]),
                            row[1], dateTime,
                            Integer.parseInt(row[2]));
                    System.out.println(message.toString());
                    messages.add(message);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            }

        }));
    }




@Override
public CameraMessage generate() {
    if (messages.isEmpty()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return messages.remove(0);

}
```

Here I have my **generator config** because I'm using spring:

```
@Configuration
public class GeneratorConfig {


@Value("${filemode.folder}")
private String folderpath;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="load", havingValue = "file")
    public MessageGenerator fileGenerator(){
         return new FileGenerator(folderpath);
    }

     @Bean
     @ConditionalOnProperty(name="load", havingValue = "random")
     public MessageGenerator randomMessageGenerator(){
         return new RandomMessageGenerator();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at Spring integration. It can read files in folders and you can activate multiple threads by configuration. Very powerfull

Comment: Thank you definitely going to do that! Do you have some documentation

Comment: The files are parsed in the constructor (when the app first starts).  Do any files exist at that point?  If yes, debug and step through the running code.  Were any files found?  Also, the code is not thread safe since multiple threads could attempt to add to `messages` at the same time.

Comment: Yess files are there! But now if I think of it, you're right it's not treath safe, any idea how I can make the adding threadsafe?

Comment: Don't do this: `new File(dir + folderpath);`. Do this: `new File(dir, folderpath);`